# Downloading a PDF from threejs visualizer

Tags: pdf, three.js, pdfrenderer

I need to download a PDF from the three visualizer canvas. I'm trying 
to use jsPDF but im getting a white pdf.

```
        function Download()
        {
            render();

            var imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
            var imgNode = document.createElement("img");
            imgNode.src = imgData;
            imgNode.id = "screenshot";
            document.body.appendChild(imgNode);

            doc.fromHTML(
            document.getElementById("screenshot"), 15, 15,
            {
            'width': window.innerWidth, // max width of content on PDF
            'elementHandlers': elementHandler
            },
            function() {
                doc.save('saveInCallback.pdf');
         });
        }
```

Manage to get the img html with the image on its src but when i download the pdf its still blank.

Comment: I've made this work by first extracting the contents of the canvas into an image, then using it with jsPDF.

Comment: And how do you extract the content ?  im new developing with threejs and html and css.  would appreciate your help. Thanks